# How can I select one month row when I have multiple rows of the same month?

Tags: r, data-analysis

My data frame is :

[image]

I want to select rows in a way so that I have one row for one month and there will be no other row for any of the days of that specific month. For example: in the dataframe you can see the first 4 row have data about the month of january. I want only one of these rows for the month of january. Same goes for other months (I have 3 years of data). If possible I want the first available date of that particular month. How can I do this?

Comment: `df %>% groupby(mnt = strftime(as.Date(date), "%b-%Y"))%>%slice_head(1)`

Comment: Also do not post images, post the data

Comment: @onyambu how do I upload date here?

Comment: just copy the data and paste it as a table. or run `dput(your_data)` and paste the results in your question

Comment: Instead of images just post the data in text. How did you manage to upload an image? Good. Do the same with text data.

Comment: @onyambu where should i run dput? can you explicitly describe every steps? I am new and learning. It will be a lot of help.

Comment: How do you run R code? dput is r code. Whether you run it on rstudio on the r console or even on rgui or as a script it does not matter. Just copy the results and paste them. Or you can simply copy your data and paste it as a table. It's your choice. I am curious how you were able to share the data as a image yet you are unable to do the same as a text. As an image, you must have double clicked it or run view. So am sure you are on rstudio. Just  copy the data from the console and paste it